# Can you plug in the 12" MacBook USB type-c > HDMI / type-A / type-c dongle directly into power supply?

Tags: macbook, usb-c

I want to plug a display into my 12" MacBook at the same time it's charging. However - this leaves a heavy dongle hanging off the machine - which isn't ideal, specially when using it on your lap.

All dongles seem to have short leads. Is there a (safe) way to do something like extend the length of the type-c run to the dongle? Or could I plug the dongle directly into the power brick - then run the type-c cable to my mac - and the HDMI cable to the screen?

(I realise the latter probably won't work - and may damage something so I haven't tried it - but it seems there definitely should be a solution to this).

Is there some kind of 'hub' that type-c power comes into - that is then outputted to my mac - and which also carries the video signal? (1 or 2 kickstarter projects exist - but they are a long way off).

I have read on Google (I forget where) - that extension leads aren't part of the type-c spec. Also that sub standard USB type-c cabling is damaging hardware.

Comment: I'm confused here - which part is using a type-c connection?

Comment: The MacBook has a type-c connector - as does its power supply. I want to have the MacBook on power & outputting to an HDMI TV - without a heavy dongle hanging off it. That's it.